# How can I install "calibration" function from the sklearn package?

Tags: python, calibration

I'm get the following error when using calibration:

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV

clf_sigmoid = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv=2, method='sigmoid')

ImportError: No module named calibration
```

calibration by default is not in sklearn package. I am unsung anaconda on Mac with python 2.7

Any help?

Rgds valerio

Comment: Looks like you can get it at: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/calibration.py

Answer (score 1):

Just install the latest version of scikit-learn.

```
sudo pip install -U scikit-learn
```